# Using PHP to connect to a remote MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, remote-access

My local environment is WAMP. For a few pages i have to access a remotely hosted MSSQL DB, run queries and get back results.

I have been supplied the following information(values masked):

- IP address of the remote MSSQL machine: 11.22.33.44
- Database Name: abcdefgh
- Username: db_username
- Password: db_password

I have never connected to a remotely hosted DB before. From the example at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

I tried this in a test file, mssql-connect.php:

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = '11.22.33.44\abcdefgh';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'db_username', 'db_password');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
?>
```

I am somehow not able to connect. I tried all variations of the connection string:

```
$server = '11.22.33.44/abcdefgh';

$server = 'http://11.22.33.44\abcdefgh';

$server = 'https://11.22.33.44\abcdefgh';

$server = '11.22.33.44';

$server = '11.22.33.44:1431';

$server = '11.22.33.44,1431';
```

Every one of these(and variations of these) return 'Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL'.

I have enabled mssql through php.ini and can see it phpinfo. Are there any additional strings that needs to be passed?

Comment: Try `$server = '11.22.33.44',1433;` - this should work if it's a default instance and remote connections are enabled and there is no firewall in your way. If it's a named instance, you should include that information in your question. Database name is not part of the server name in the connection string. Also, can you connect to this server from Management Studio? Maybe try there before debugging PHP code, and also connecting with the support team at the host - if they're hosting SQL Server for you, they know how to help you connect to it.

Comment: I just tried `$server = '11.22.33.44',1433;` and got the response 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\path_to_my_file\mssql-connect.php on line 26'.

Comment: There is no firewall since i am accessing this over my normal internet connection on my computer (default settings). 

I was informed that remote connections have been enabled in the remote DB. Not sure if it is a default or named instance. Will edit the question when i get this info. Will try via Management Studio now. The web host is LAMP-based and i checked the phpinfo and found that they don't have mssql enabled. I will be contacting them tomorrow to have it enabled.

 I wanted to get the connection going before attempting it off my host.

Comment: Sorry, `$server = '11.22.33.44,1433';`. Also, your local computer is not the only place where a firewall might exist.

Comment: Just quickly checked after removing the comma(and thus the port also). It  returns 'Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 11.222.33.44 in C:\path_to_file\mssql-connect.php on line 29
Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL'.

Comment: Line 26: $server = '11.22.33.44';

Comment: Tried `$server = '11.22.33.44,1433';`. Returns the error '_Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 11.22.33.44,1433 in C:\path_to_file\mssql-connect.php on line 31
Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL_'. Line 31 is `$link = mssql_connect($server, 'db_username', 'db_password');`.

Comment: (1) Just wonder: Did you try using "sa" to login ? `mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'sa_password');` (2) Assuming that the MSSQL is run in default port , then try `11.22.33.44\abcdefgh` (something like `11.22.33.44\SQLEXPRESS`)

Answer (score 0):

First, dont provide full access to your database here (unless your user and password are just placeholders).
Second, You have to be sure that the host where your SQL is running, has enabled remote access. If your MSSQL server has not enabled remote access, no matter how you try to connect, you will always fail.

Comment: Regarding DB access information, agreed, its a very valid point. I haven't added any information. My question had this line: 'I have been supplied the following information**(values masked)**'. About remote access, as far as i recall, i think this was mentioned. I will double-check this now.

Comment: Just confirmed, remote access is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
       $server = '11.22.33.44';
      // Connect to MSSQL
      $link = mssql_connect($server, 'db_username', 'db_password');
```

above code should work only thing is that mssql is not allowed to configured remotely so its blocking access to your ip. you have to enable mssql to get accessed remotely

Comment: ok, but i did get confirmation that remote access is enabled. Is there is a 'php-specific' access that has to be enabled?  Or is the setting/enabling a global configuration that allows all access? Perhaps something needs to be added to the mssql server specifically allowing access to a call from a php file/source? I have these questions are because i got confirmation about the enablement of remote access.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after some playing around I finally got it to connect using sqlsrv_query()

Not sure if it because of PHP version updates or something.

Do some research on this, it worked for me.

Comment: `sqlsrv_query()` is something i didn't try. Will definitely check this out asap. Not right away, as ive been making code changes to push data to the immediately(locally) available mySQL DB in some areas that required quick data read-write.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect with that codes successfully.

```
$username ="WRITEUSER";
$password = "WRITEPASS";
$database = "WRITEDB";
$server = "WRITESERVERIP";

$connection = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());} 


$db_selected = mssql_select_db($databaseb, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} else{

    // Success
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

to connect your database remotely you must create the user account in your phpmyadmin and allow the privileges to that user account. while connecting to the database remotely use the username and password information which you specified while creating the user account.

Comment: This question is about SQL Server, not MySQL